# How to raise a number to a power?

Tags: rust, operators, exponentiation

I was trying to raise an integer to a power using the caret operator (`^`), but I am getting surprising results, e.g.:

```
assert_eq!(2^10, 8);
```

How can I perform exponentiation in Rust?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Rust provides exponentiation via methods [`pow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.pow) and [`checked_pow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.checked_pow). The latter
guards against overflows. Thus, to raise 2 to the power of 10, do:

```
let base: i32 = 2; // an explicit type is required
assert_eq!(base.pow(10), 1024);
```

The caret operator `^` is not used for exponentiation, it's the [bitwise XOR
operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.BitXor.html).

Comment: is this optimized by `2 << 9` ?

Comment: @Stargateur In such cases the compiler optimizes the whole operation away, but it doesn't seem like it when the base is not known: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/VJKgn1).

Comment: just tried this as a part of a constant and got the error that it is unstable for use in a constant. Putting it out in case someone else is trying the same. I'm on `rustc 1.54.0 (a178d0322 2021-07-26)`

Answer (score 43):

Here is the simplest method which you can use:

```
let a = 2; // Can also explicitly define type i.e. i32
let a = i32::pow(a, 10);
```

It will output "2 raised to the power of 10", i.e.:

> 1024

Comment: This also worked for me

i32::pow(2, 10); // 1024

Answer (score 16):

For integers:

```
fn main() {
   let n = u32::pow(2, 10);
   println!("{}", n == 1024);
}
```

For floats:

```
fn main() {
   // example 1
   let f = f32::powf(2.0, 10.0);
   // example 2
   let g = f32::powi(2.0, 10);
   // print
   println!("{}", f == 1024.0 && g == 1024.0);
}
```

or, since your base is 2, you can also use shift:

```
fn main() {
   let n = 2 << 9;
   println!("{}", n == 1024);
}
```

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.powf
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.powi
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.pow

Comment: `2<<9` is an odd choice; why not `4<<8` or `64<<4`? If what you want is 2 to the _10th_ power, to me it seems that the most logical expression is the one with a 10 in it: `1<<10`.

Answer (score 10):

I was trying the same thing as the OP. Thanks to the other answer authors.

Here's a variation that works for me:

```
let n = 2u32.pow(10);
```

This uses a [literal unsigned 32 bit integer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/types/literals.html) to set the type and base, then calls the `pow()` function on it.

Answer (score 5):

Bit shifting is a good way to do this particular case:

```
assert_eq!(1 << 10, 1024);
```

Comment: Nice and clean!

Answer (score 3):

There's a shortcut for a literal in scientific notation.
The number `1e9` is a literal for `1 * i32::pow(10, 9)`.