# How can I guarantee that overflow will not occur in const variables?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, constants, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer

I can describe the dimension of this "circular" hexgrid..

[image: circular hex grid]

.. with only 1 value `n` defined at compile time:

```
const GRID_RADIUS: usize = 3;
```

Therefore, the number of cells in the grid is also known at compile time, since it is `(2n+1)^2-n*(n+1)` (here 37).

However, the following:

```rust
const N: usize = 3;
const N_CELLS: usize = ((2 * N + 1) ^ 2) - N * (N + 1);

struct Cell;

struct Grid {
    cells: [Cell; N_CELLS],
}
```

Does not compile:

```
error: any use of this value will cause an error
 --> src/main.rs:2:34
  |
2 | const N_CELLS: usize = ((2 * N + 1) ^ 2) - N * (N + 1);
  | -----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
  |                        |
  |                        attempt to subtract with overflow
  |
  = note: `#[deny(const_err)]` on by default
```

I understand that `rustc` worries that subtracting `usize` types may result in overflow, but I can guarantee that `N_CELLS` will always be positive in this case.

How can I take responsibility for this and have `rustc` trust me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no guarantee to be made — constant values are evaluated at compile time. The compiler **knows** if a value overflowed because it performed the calculation.

> I understand that `rustc` worries that subtracting `usize` types may result in overflow, but I can guarantee that `N_CELLS` will always be positive in this case.
>
> How can I take responsibility for this and have `rustc` trust me?

You cannot guarantee this (and the compiler shouldn't trust you) because **you are incorrect**. `^` means XOR, not "to the power of". The compiler executed your code and literally subtracted below zero, triggering the error. This is not hypothetical:

```
((2 * n) ^ 2) = 4
n * (n + 1) = 12
4 - 12 = -8
```

```
fn main() {
    let n: usize = 3;
    let n_cells: usize = ((2 * n) ^ 2) - n * (n + 1);
}
```

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to subtract with overflow', src/main.rs:3:26
```

In fact, [thanks to this question](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71134), Rust now shows the values that cause the overflow, hopefully making the original mistake clearer :

```
 --> src/lib.rs:2:24
  |
2 | const N_CELLS: usize = ((2 * N + 1) ^ 2) - N * (N + 1);
  | -----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
  |                        |
  |                        attempt to compute `5_usize - 12_usize` which would overflow
  |
  = note: `#[deny(const_err)]` on by default
```

See also:

- [How to raise a number to a power?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51208703/155423)

Unfortunately, you cannot currently use `pow` in a constant:

```
const N: usize = 3;
const N_CELLS: usize = ((2 * N + 1).pow(2)) - N * (N + 1);
```

```
error[E0015]: calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
 --> src/lib.rs:2:24
  |
2 | const N_CELLS: usize = ((2 * N + 1).pow(2)) - N * (N + 1);
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You will have to expand the multiplication yourself:

```
const N_CELLS: usize = {
    let a = 2 * N + 1;
    let b = N * (N + 1);
    a * a - b
};
```

Comment: Wops. Yes, I am incorrect. Sorry for that. I read that `core::num::<impl usize>::pow is not yet stable as a const fn`, but it works fine with `(2 * N + 1) * (2 * N + 1)` instead.