# When I try to use the exponentiation operator in Rust, it gives strange results. Why?

Tags: rust, exponentiation, bitwise-xor

I am trying to implement Complex-Step Differentiation in Rust. However, when raising the complex number to a power higher than 2, I get a completely different result than Julia. The algorithm works in Julia for any function but in Rust, it only works for second-order functions.

Here are the ways I raise the imaginary number to a power in both languages.

In Rust:

```rust
let x: f64 = 1.0;
let h: f64 = f64::from(1*10^-8);

println!("Result = {:?}", (num::pow(Complex::new(x,h),3));
// Complex { re: -587.0, im: 2702.0 }
```

In Julia:

```julia
h = 1*10^-8
x = 1
println((x+im*h)^3)
# 0.9999999999999997 + 3.000000000000001e-8im
```

I have no idea as to how I could do this so any help is very welcome.

Comment: `^` is not an exponentiation operator, but bitwise XOR. You may have meant to write `1e-8`

Comment: I can't believe that's the solution... I have been using .powi() and num::pow() everywhere in my code but there. Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to raise a number to a power?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208703/how-to-raise-a-number-to-a-power)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust has no exponentiation operator.

The binary operator `^` is not exponentiation, but bitwise exclusive-or.  This is an operation defined only for integer types, and it returns the number whose set of set bits is the symmetric difference of the sets of set bits of the operands.  `1 * 10 ^ -8` thus computes (assuming the 32-bit signed type, which is what type inference assigns to this expression by default) `0x0000000a` ⊕ `0xfffffff8`, which is `0xfffffff2`, i.e. −14.

If you want to specify a floating-point number in exponential notation, you can use the E notation:

```rust
let h: f64 = 1e-8;
```

For arbitrary exponentiation, since you already have the `num` crate, you might as well use `num::pow`.